increase #cpu in worker in dataflow prime
I use beam python on dataflow prime. My python code calls a c++ binary through subprocess. The c++ process is CPU intensive, currently takes hours and dominates the wall time of the dataflow job.
Is there a way (or will there be a way soon) to increase the number of CPUs for each of the c++ subprocess? I see "right fitting", but it seems only for RAM and GPU.
If not, I assume the classic dataflow supports designating specific VM types. What's the downside of switching from prime to classic? Lack of vertical auto-scaling of RAM?
My current flags:
--dataflow_service_options=enable_dynamic_thread_scaling,
--experiments=enable_batch_vmr,
--experiments=enable_vertical_memory_autoscaling,

# flex-template build
--additional-experiments=enable_prime

